# Django admin login redirect to next page

Tags: django, redirect, authentication, admin

I have just upgraded my site from Django 1.2.5 to 1.3 and am in the process of fixing some errors. The login for the admin part of the site used to work, however since the upgrade django returns a 404 error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://example.com/accounts/profile/

Using the URLconf defined in urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^admin_tools/
    ^admin/filebrowser/
    ^grappelli/
    ^admin/galleries/
    admin/list_orders[/]
    ^admin/
    ^404$
    ^robots\.txt$
    ^events/
    ^memberships/
    ^shop/
    ^accounts/ ^register_login/(?P<activation_key>\w+)[/]$ [name='registration_activate']
    ^accounts/ ^login[/]$ [name='auth_login']
    ^accounts/ ^logout[/]$ [name='auth_logout']
    ^accounts/ ^password/change[/]$ [name='auth_password_change']
    ^accounts/ ^password/change/done[/]$ [name='auth_password_change_done']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset[/]$ [name='auth_password_reset']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb36>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)[/]$ [name='auth_password_reset_confirm']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/complete[/]$ [name='auth_password_reset_complete']
    ^accounts/ ^password/reset/done[/]$ [name='auth_password_reset_done']
    ^accounts/ ^register_login[/]$ [name='register_login']
    ^accounts/ ^register_complete[/]$ [name='registration_complete']
    ^profile
    ^emailmgr/
    ^cart/
    ^stripe/webhooks/$
    ^order/checkout/$
    ^order/promotion/$
    ^order/show/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='show-order']
    ^order/status/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$ [name='order-status']
    ^order/check_status/$ [name='check-order-status']
    ^order/complete_order/$ [name='complete-order']
    ^order/shipping_method/$
    ^order/vat_value/$
    ^order/vat_value_gift/$
    ^order/vat_label/$
    ^order/free_download/(?P<p_product_id>[0-9]+)/$
    ^admin/order/shipping-label-html/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$
    ^admin/order/shipping-label/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$
    ^admin/order/invoice-html/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$
    ^admin/order/invoice/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)/$
    ^admin/order/send_email/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)[/]$
    ^admin/order/send_email_gmail/(?P<p_order_id>[0-9]+)[/]$
    ^admin/order/incomplete_remove[/]$
    thank-you-for-order/$ [name='show-order']
    ^checkout/
    ^people/
    ^artists/$
    ^artists/(?P<p_slug>[a-z\-_0-9]+)/$ [name='people_detail']
    ^ ^menus/(?P<p_menu_category_slug>[a-z\-_0-9]+)[/]$
    ^ ^(?P<p_page_slug>[a-z\-_0-9]+)[/]$
    ^ ^$
    ^media/(?P<path>.*)$

The current URL, accounts/profile/, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I know I can set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py to a static URL, however the site used to work with the next parameter, ie:

http://example.com/admin/events

which would take you to the events admin page after logging in.

So something has changed in 1.3 where this no longer works. How can I fix this error?

here's the form:

```
<form action="{{ app_path }}" method="post" id="login-form">{% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="module">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column span-4"><label for="id_username" class="required">{% trans 'Username:' %}</label></div>
            <div class="column span-6 last"><input type="text" name="username" id="id_username" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column span-4"><label for="id_password" class="required">{% trans 'Password:' %}</label></div>
            <div class="column span-6 last"><input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" /><input type="hidden" name="this_is_the_login_form" value="1" /></div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="module submit-row">
        <ul class="submit-row">
            <li class="submit-button-container"><input type="submit" class="default" value="{% trans 'Log in' %}" /></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

and the 'pip freeze':

```
Django==1.3
MySQL-python==1.2.5
Pillow==2.5.3
PyPDF2==1.22
argparse==1.2.1
boto==2.36.0
django-boto==0.3.9
django-s3-folder-storage==0.3
django-s3-storage==0.9.8
django-storages==1.1.3
html5lib==0.999
oauthlib==0.6.3
pisa==3.0.33
python-dateutil==2.5.3
python-twitter==2.0
reportlab==3.1.8
requests==2.3.0
requests-oauthlib==0.4.1
simplejson==3.6.0
six==1.7.3
stripe==1.18.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
xhtml2pdf==0.0.6
```

Comment: Please post your login form.

Comment: post a 'pip freeze'

Comment: If you're already in a process of upgrading your code - I would suggest to go with a maintained version. 1.3 is form 2011 and not supported since years... So you should consider upgrading to 1.8 (which has LTS until 2018)

Comment: your file "requirements.txt" seems incomplete. Grappelli and filebrowser are not there

Comment: The problem with upgrading to 1.8 is that the site doesn't work at all - I think because of this error: ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager which I have not found a solution for. And I believe I will still be stuck with the current error (and many more I expect).

Comment: @alexander Grappelli and filebrowser are custom modules so I am not sure how they can be imported? I have run: `python manage.py shell` `import grappelli` `grappelli.VERSION` which returns `'2.2'` and then added this to the requirements.txt file but there is no change. `filebrowser.VERSION` returns an error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VERSION'`